# Find and remove all non numbers from array in JavaScript w/out JQuery

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There was a question on a coding interview and I felt like it would be easy by using `isNaN` within a for loop and then splicing that index. Come to find out it didn't work and I haven't found a single thing online that shows how to do it. This is without jQuery and just strictly ES6 javascript. Say you are given an array..... `arr = [2, "a", 4, "b", 3, 5, "c"]`. Without making a new array, modify the existing array to contain only numbers. How would you go about removing all non-numbers from the array? I have not found one solution online that does not use jQuery.

Comment: The problem you are facing is that [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) doesn't return `true` if the value is some type other than `number` -- it returns `true` if the input is [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).  So for instance `Number.isNaN('b')` will be `false` but `Number.isNaN(3/'b')` will be `true`.

Comment: What about `"2"`? Number or string?

Comment: `without jQuery` - just as well, as there is nothing in jQuery that will do this

Comment: Amadan -- they did not mention that situation in the question, but that is something that crossed my mind. I was only given 15 min so I was kind of rushed.

Comment: Bravo -- Everything I saw used Jquery shorthands to compare the array. I wasn't saying there was a one-word use in jQuery to make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array.splice is useful here. I'm sure this solution can be optimized.

```
array.forEach((item, index) => typeof item !== 'number' && array.splice(index, 1));
```

Comment: I was really close to a solution like this. I did not include index. What confuses me about this is the &&.

Comment: This is shorthand syntax. In JavaScript, if it’s true, it’ll go to the next expression and evaluate it. You’ll see the same sort of thing with a logical OR ||, like when needing to set a default on a variable. In the OR case, if the first value coerces to false, it’ll go to the next expression (like a default value), but if it evaluates to true, it’ll stick with that first value.

Comment: The `&&` here is being used as a sort of conditional logic stand-in for an `if` block-- if `typeof item !== 'number' evaluates to `true`, the `array.splice(index, 1))` will be evaluated-- if it evaluates to `false`, then the callback will exit and go to the next iteration of the `forEach` loop.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on this. Both of these solutions are exactly what I was looking for. I have a hard time choosing which one should be the accepted solution. You both have been extremely helpful and informative. Thank you

Comment: I was curious to see which one was more performant and forEach (this solution) seems to come out ahead. https://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-for-splice/1

Comment: @RossSheppard I do agree that it fits more with the lines of ES6 and for performance. I will select it as the answer. Thank you again for your help.